# Python OpenCV: Using matchTemplate

Tags: python, opencv

I have two surfaces, a large one [image: surface image]

and a smaller one [image]

I'm trying to adapt a [template matching tutorial](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/01/26/multi-scale-template-matching-using-python-opencv/) to these surfaces by treating them as grey-scale images.

I need to update the tutorial to scale independently in x and y, I've done this but adding an additional loop. My code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

# If True shows each iteration of the template matching
Visualise = True

# Load in image and template
image = pd.read_excel('TemplateMatching_exampleData.xlsx',sheetname="radial_template").as_matrix().astype(np.float32)
template = pd.read_excel('TemplateMatching_exampleData.xlsx',sheetname="radial_image").as_matrix().T.astype(np.float32)

# Save a raw copy of the template
template_raw = template

# Rescale the template to approximate the same range in values as the image
template = template - np.mean(template)
template = (template/np.max(template)) * np.max(image)

# Get the height and width of the template
(tH, tW) = template.shape[:2]

# initialize the bookkeeping variable to keep track of the matched region
found = None

# If visualise = True then initialise the figure to show the iteration
if Visualise:
    fig1 = plt.figure()
    ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)

# loop over the scales of the image
for scale_width in np.linspace(0.1, 2, 20):
    for scale_height in np.linspace(0.1, 3, 20)[::-1]:
        # resize the image according to the scale, and keep track
        # of the ratio of the resizing
        resized = cv2.resize(image, ( int(image.shape[0] * scale_height), int(image.shape[1] * scale_width) ))
        r_h = image.shape[0] / float(resized.shape[0])
        r_w = image.shape[1] / float(resized.shape[1])

        # if the resized image is smaller than the template, then break
        # from the loop
        if resized.shape[0] < tH or resized.shape[1] < tW:
            break

        # apply template matching to find the template in the image
        result = cv2.matchTemplate(resized, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF)
        (_, maxVal, _, maxLoc) = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)

        # check to see if the iteration should be visualized
        if Visualise:
            ax1.clear()
            ax1.imshow(resized)
            ax1.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((maxLoc[0], maxLoc[1]), tW, tH, fill=False, edgecolor = 'red'))
            plt.show()
            plt.draw()
            plt.pause(0.05) # fig1.waitforbuttonpress()

        # if we have found a new maximum correlation value, then update
        # the bookkeeping variable
        if found is None or maxVal > found[0]:
            found = (maxVal, maxLoc, r_w, r_h, scale_width, scale_height)

# unpack the bookkeeping varaible and compute the (x, y) coordinates
# of the bounding box based on the resized ratio
(_, maxLoc, r_w, r_h, scale_width, scale_height) = found
(startX, startY) = (int(maxLoc[0] * r_w), int(maxLoc[1] * r_h))
(endX, endY) = (int((maxLoc[0] + tW) * r_w), int((maxLoc[1] + tH) * r_h))

# draw a bounding box around the detected result and display the image
figure = plt.figure()
ax1 = figure.add_subplot(111)
ax1.imshow(image)
ax1.add_patch(patches.Rectangle((startX,startY), endX-startX, endY-startY, fill=False, edgecolor = 'red'))
plt.show()
plt.draw()

# show the matching image segment and template together
plt.figure()
plt.subplot(121)
plt.imshow(image[startX:endX, startY:endY])
plt.title('Image')
plt.subplot(122)
plt.imshow(template)
plt.title('Template')
```

What I am finding however is that the "optimal fit" is always found at the largest `scale_width` value, regardless of what I set this value to be, but I can't figure out why. I'm guessing it's a result of how the fit is measured, but I don't know enough about `cv2.matchTemplate` to be able to correct for it and I've been agonizing over this for days.

Please can you help me fix my code?

I've copied my data from my Excel file to [this GoogleDocs document](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jBtD1hUD0yX-d4Tg2rxSh7KxOfn_uUZxHMiR4EMJH-w/edit?usp=sharing) .

Comment: 1. It's probably better to divide by the standard deviation (simply `numpy.std(array)`) than just to scale by the max; shifting the mean and diving by std dev gives you a distribution with 0 mean and unit standard dev. 2. You should scale both the template and the image that way to get both have a similar distribution. 3. You can either share the Excel data in a public Google sheet or similar, or scale the grayscale values exactly between 0 and 1 float or between 0 and 255 uint8 and save them as grayscale images with OpenCV `imwrite()` and post those for us to load.

Comment: Thanks, I've added a link to the data in the main post

Comment: Looking at the values in your spreadsheet, did you actually scale the `image` too or just the `template`? Because your template after being divided by the `max` will have a max value of `1` while your `image` has a max value of like `10000` so you won't get any close matches. Try scaling both of them, either with std deviation like I mentioned or even just naively shift/scale them both into 0 and 1 and see if you get matches that way. Because otherwise, just going off that tutorial and stretching your template should work relatively well.

Comment: Also slightly confusing on the naming here, your radial image is the smaller one, but in your code you read the template as the image and the image as the template, might want to clear that up a bit better.

Comment: I've scaled both to a [0,1] range by subtracting the min value and dividing by the range. I'm still finding that the scales that I find aren't optimal, even visually I can see that. I misnamed the arrays in my Excel file, sorry about that.

Comment: It seems the template is rotated 90 degrees? Should it be detecting this rotation or no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Starting with a problem you *can* solve

So first off there's some bookkeeping that needs to be done---it seems the `image` and `template` are switched in the Excel doc and further it seems the `template` is actually rotated 90 degrees. To get something that *works*, I'll scale the template manually to roughly the right size and make sure that the template can be found. Note that I exported each sheet as a `.csv` file and corrected the names.

Further, I set the images to have a mean of zero and a standard deviation of one, just by subtracting off the mean and dividing by the standard deviation. This should keep the images in roughly the same distribution for good matching along highly different values in the original arrays.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = np.genfromtxt('radial_img.csv', delimiter=',').astype(np.float32)
tmp = np.genfromtxt('radial_tmp.csv', delimiter=',').astype(np.float32)
tmp = np.rot90(tmp)
tmp = cv2.resize(tmp, None, fx=0.5, fy=0.33)

img = (img - np.mean(img))/np.std(img)
tmp = (tmp - np.mean(tmp))/np.std(tmp)

ccorr = cv2.matchTemplate(img, tmp, cv2.TM_CCORR)
tl = cv2.minMaxLoc(ccorr)[3]
h, w = tmp.shape[:2]
br = (tl[0]+w, tl[1]+h)

matched = cv2.normalize(img, None, alpha=0, beta=1, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
matched = cv2.merge([matched, matched, matched])
cv2.rectangle(matched, tl, br, (0, 255, 0))
cv2.imshow('matched0.png', matched)
cv2.waitKey()
```

[image: Matched with manual resize]

Great! It works! Note that here the template is actually pretty small, way smaller than it should be, but we still got the rough location so we know we're on the right track.

## Looping through multiple sizes

Now we just have to create those loops you made and resize the template multiple times until we get the best match. Note however that the methods for template matching all have a scale associated with the size of the template, so smaller templates will have smaller errors. Thus we need to use the `_NORMED` methods to make sure the results are mostly scale invariant. Instead of creating multiple `for` loops and resizing inside, I think it's clearer to just use a list comprehension to build all the resized images, and then loop over all of those images. We can store the best result as we go along, and then after we're done display the best result. Note that all normalizing here is strictly for visualizing; it's not necessary for using the OpenCV functions:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = np.genfromtxt('radial_img.csv', delimiter=',').astype(np.float32)
tmp = np.genfromtxt('radial_tmp.csv', delimiter=',').astype(np.float32)
tmp = np.rot90(tmp)

img = (img - np.mean(img))/np.std(img)
tmp = (tmp - np.mean(tmp))/np.std(tmp)

sz_ranges = np.linspace(0.1, 2.0, 19)
resized_tmps = [cv2.resize(tmp, None, fx=i, fy=j)
                for i in sz_ranges for j in sz_ranges]
n_tmps = len(resized_tmps)

for rs_tmp, k in zip(resized_tmps, range(n_tmps)):
    ccorr = cv2.matchTemplate(img, rs_tmp, cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED)
    match_val, match_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(ccorr)[1::2]
    if k == 0:
        best_match_val = match_val
    if match_val > best_match_val:
        best_match_val = match_val
        best_match_loc = match_loc
        best_match = k

best_match_tmp = resized_tmps[best_match]
best_match_tmp = cv2.normalize(best_match_tmp, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX).astype(np.uint8)
best_match_tmp = cv2.merge([best_match_tmp, best_match_tmp, best_match_tmp])

h, w = best_match_tmp.shape[:2]
best_match_loc_end = (best_match_loc[0]+w, best_match_loc[1]+h)
matched = cv2.normalize(img, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX).astype(np.uint8)
matched = cv2.merge([matched, matched, matched])
cv2.rectangle(matched, best_match_loc, best_match_loc_end, (0, 255, 0))

cv2.imshow('matched1.png', matched)
cv2.waitKey()

cv2.imshow('besttmp.png', best_match_tmp)
cv2.waitKey()
```

And again, it works!

[image: Matched after auto-resizing]

Here's the template that matched the best:

[image: Best matched template]

Which by visual inspection looks to be about right. The height and width of the best matched template was `(85, 99)` which is basically just the original template with a bit of a horizontal stretch.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was the most detailed, useful, answer I could ask for :D